# Awareness API Query for Fence State

Tags: android, google-awareness

I am trying to get fence state with the Awareness API. Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/fence-query-state) about this. But... When using:

```
Awareness.FenceApi.queryFences
```

I can see its [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/awareness/Awareness), and instead need to use:

```
Awareness.getFenceClient
```

Can anyone please give me an example how to get fence status with getFenceClient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it:

```
Awareness.getFenceClient(context).queryFences(FenceQueryRequest.forFences(Arrays.asList(key)))
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FenceQueryResponse>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FenceQueryResponse fenceQueryResponse) {

                    FenceStateMap map = fenceQueryResponse.getFenceStateMap();

                    for (String fenceKey : map.getFenceKeys()) {
                        FenceState fenceState = map.getFenceState(fenceKey);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Fence " + fenceKey + ": "
                                + fenceState.getCurrentState()
                                + ", was="
                                + fenceState.getPreviousState());
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed: " + e);
                }
            });
```